# Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/clipboard

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use angular material and after installing I got this error. my package.json.
I'm using angular 8 and tried to changes to the versions of angular material.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

try using installing this

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ng add @angular/material` to install Angular Material to your project. This will automatically install the CDK and other dependencies of Angular Material.

Documentation Reference Link [Click Here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I generated it again using angular cli which prevented all these errors.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

will resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the clipboard is supported from Angular9.